# Golang with postgres - unable to pass variable into a ST_DWithin query

Tags: postgresql, go, postgis

Very new to Golang and unable to resolve this. Any help would be highly appreciated.

This is the code I need help with. Trying to pass the latitude etc into the query below, but unable to do it. Looking for the equivalent on ${latitude} in node js...

```golang
   latitude := r.URL.Query().Get("lat")
   longitude := r.URL.Query().Get("lon")
   radius := r.URL.Query().Get("rad")


   row := db.QueryRow(`SELECT "name", "website", "coordinates", 
   "description", "rating"
    FROM geospots
    WHERE ST_DWithin("coordinates", ST_MakePoint(latitude = $1, 
   longitude = $2)::geography, radius = $3)`, latitude, longitude)


   Error: 
   andlers/SpotsInArea.go:15:5: latitude declared but not used
   handlers/SpotsInArea.go:16:5: longitude declared but not used
   handlers/SpotsInArea.go:17:5: radius declared but not used
```

Comment: Go doesn't have native string interpolation. And certainly not with builtin sql-injection protection. If you want to pass the variables as arguments to the query pass them as arguments to the `QueryRow` method just after the SQL string. And also you need to put parameter placeholders into the SQL string. For postgres it's `$1`, `$2`, and so on.

Comment: As an example take a look at [this](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/lib/pq#hdr-Queries). You can see that there the SQL string uses `$1` once and `$2` twice and then passes two arguments `"orange"` and `64`. The `$1` in the SQL will be replaced with `"orange"` and the two `$2` will both be replaced with `64`.

Comment: mkopriva Thanks very much for taking the time to reply. Based on that, I would have thought that the following code would have worked, but it doesn't. It's looking for columns with these titles. It also doesn't accept any hardcoded values there. Can you see what I am doing wrong?  row := db.QueryRow(`SELECT "name", "website", "coordinates", "description", "rating"
    FROM geospots
    WHERE ST_DWithin("coordinates", ST_MakePoint(latitude = $1, longitude = $2)::geography, radius = $3)`, latitude, longitude)

Comment: Update the question with the new code. Also, include the exact error message that you are getting.

Comment: mkopriva - Done. Thanks again for the effort.

Comment: It should be **just** `$1` instead of `latitude = $1`. Same for the other three parameters. And you MUST pass **all** three arguments not just lat and long, i.e. where is radius? And the error means that lat long and radius are declared in a scope where they are not used. That means that the QueryRow that you have show is executed in some other function which has no access to those three variables. In Go `v := x` does not declare global variables if that's what you were hoping for.

Comment: mkopriva - Superb! Thank you so very, very, very much - lifesaver you are!@

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @mkopirva

As pointed you don't need `latitude = $1` it should be just `$1`, You have defined `$3` in query but missing the 3rd value

And make sure the variable are within the scope where you are accessing them

```golang
row := db.QueryRow(`
SELECT
    "name",
    "website",
    "coordinates",
    "description",
    "rating"
FROM
    geospots
WHERE
    ST_DWithin(
        "coordinates",
        ST_MakePoint($1, $2)::geography,
        $3
    )`,
    longitude, latitude, radius
)
```